# How to ignore Runtime Errors even when NaNs are populated from np.nanstd? - Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, runtime-error

From the code below, I am trying to slice three columns of dataframe. 
Put that in a numpy array in an horizontal line then reshape by (no of data/15 and 15) --> Here i attempted to group every 15 data into a row and calculate its standard deviation.

I would try to ignore the NaNs in the dataframe even if there are any. Thus I have used np.nanstd.

The code is shown as below:

```
k=SpeedLane.iloc[:,0:3]
k = k.values
k = np.ravel(k)
k = np.reshape(k, ((len(k)//15, 15)))
Between_SL_sd = np.nanstd(k, axis=1)
```

An error occurred after executing the code:

```
C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\nanfunctions.py:1434: RuntimeWarning: Degrees of freedom <= 0 for slice. keepdims=keepdims)
```

I have browse through the Numpy document and I found out that one of the 15x array has got all NAs and returned to this error.

I acknologed that and still I want to ignore that issue. Or is there a way that I can replace that NaNs with 0 immediately and then replace that with NaN afterwards to  get rid of the warning?

Comment: Answers have provided safe ways to avoid the source of this warning, which is a better way than ignoring the warnings altogether. However, the `warnings` module from the standard library offers ways to ignore warnings. `warnings.simplefilter('ignore', category=RuntimeWarning)` turns all `RuntimeWarning`s off globally. You could wrap it in the `warnings.catch_warnings` context manager to ignore warnings locally. [Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider a 1D-array of all nan elements,

`arr = np.array([np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan])`

**np.isfinite()** -> Test element-wise for finiteness

```
bool_arr = np.isfinite(arr)
print(bool_arr)
```

Output:

```
[False False False False]
```

**any** -> will return True if there's any truth value in the iterable.

```
chk = not any(bool_arr)
print(chk)
```

Output:
`True`

This shows that all values in array are nan.Now, we can replace all nan with zeros like this,

```
arr = np.nan_to_num(arr, copy=True)
print(arr)
```

Output:
`[0. 0. 0. 0.]`

To convert back 0's to nan, do this,

```
arr[arr == 0] = 'nan' # or use np.nan
print(arr)
```

Output:
`[nan nan nan nan]`

Now, Consider an example of a dataframe like below,

```
    col1    col2    col3    col4
0   5.0     1.0     6.0      NaN
1   2.0     2.0     1.0      NaN
2   NaN     NaN     NaN      NaN
3   3.0     4.0     NaN      NaN
4   NaN     NaN     NaN      NaN
```

To get std of each row, do this,

```
    std = []
for row in range(len(df)):
    k = df.iloc[row].values
    bool_arr = np.isfinite(k)
    chk = not any(bool_arr)
    if chk == True:
        k = np.nan_to_num(k, copy=True)
    st = np.nanstd(k)
    if chk == True:
        st = np.nan
    std.append(st)

data = {'std_row_wise': std}
std_df = pd.DataFrame(data = data)

std_df
```

Output: each value of dataframe is `std` of a row.

```
   std_row_wise
0   2.160247
1   0.471405
2   NaN
3   0.500000
4   NaN
```

Comment: Still the runtime Warning populates. Would that be the case which when we try to exectue  `Between_SL_sd = np.nanstd(k, axis=1)`
When the whole row is all NaNs the calculation still recognises the error?

Comment: Before executing `Between_SL_sd = np.nanstd(k, axis=1)` I made a check `if chk == True: k = np.nan_to_num(k, copy=True)` which will assign 0 if there are all `nan` in the row, so it's not possible to throw a warning.

Comment: The warning still exists if i use your function even if the check is there.

Comment: Strange! Can you provide the value of `k` after first line of code `k=SpeedLane.iloc[:,0:3]`.

Comment: The warning still exists if i use your function even if the check is there.
It doesnt work when the if condition is applied. The dataframe K still presents  nan. when I execute the code up to reshape

Comment: After the first line of k, it is a 120 R * 3C df with some N/As in column 3

Comment: I am getting it but a little confused. Your `SpeedLane` is a dataframe as far as I am understanding. Please share the whole data of `SpeedLane`. Then, I will try to solve this problem soon.

Comment: It is a very big dataset. I will try to explain it here. So for the 24*15 array. 
there are N/As for the whole row for for some rows and some of them only got couple of N/As there. 
I aim to do the `np_nan_to_sum` for the whole row with N/As then do nan.std and perform nan.std for the others.

Comment: Do you want to find the `nan.std` by row-wise or by column-wise or you want to find `nan.std` for whole dataframe. I mean there will be one output for whole dataframe ?

Comment: nan.std by row-wise

but for the whole row with NAs I need to replace that to 0s

Comment: I have tired `bool_arr = np.all(np.isnan(k), axis=1)`. It does show that row 11 is `True`. Basically I want this `True` to enable the replacement of the NAs there to 0s

Comment: I have updated my reply with an example of input dataframe and output dataframe where each value representing `std` of each row of input dataframe without any warnings and also for rows, which contains all `nan's`, `std` is zero.

Comment: It works! Nearly there! However for that answer, the s.d. for all NaNs are 0 and I would like to change it to NaN back given actually there might be 0 for standard deviation. 
I can't use `arr[arr == 0] = 'nan'` because the other results with 0 standard deviation will actually be changed to NA

Illustration: [link](https://imgur.com/a/Fit4Obg)

Comment: why you want `NaN` back from here. They exists in input dataframe as I am not modifying original dataframe. If you want to use them, you can access them easily in original form from input dataframe.

Comment: because I need to distinguish that from 0s. 
The desired result would be (from your dataset)

`   std_row_wise
0   2.160247
1   0.471405
2   NaN
3   0.500000
4   NaN`


to avoid ambuigity from results with actual 0s in standard deviation

Comment: @JackyMan I have update the result, no need to convert `0` into `Nan`. Still, you are getting your desired result. Please accept and up-vote this answer now.

Comment: Perfect It is correct now. Thanks a lot for your help. 
I was stuck in that for loop and row as I cannot extract manipulate the answer even I have got the conditions right. I am sorry that I do not have enough reputation to upvote yet